# Removing last item when rendering in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am facing an issue where a item is getting rendered even though there is no associated `Title` with it as shown in my JSON. Please see the attached screenshot which will make you understand my problem (marked in red). I know this is happening due to `lid` in my JSON for which vue is rendering that without any associated (i.e Title) values. How do I solve this issue. Is there a way to remove the last item when rendering or is there any other way ?. I need the `lid` in `this.dino` but do not need it when rendering in my vue-app. Is there a way to pop out the last item from the JSON when rendering.

```
<div id="vue-app">
          <div id="myList" v-for="item in items">
                <p>{{item.Title}}</p>
<button v-on:click="loadmore()" class="fluid ui button">Load More</button>
```

Below is my vue function

```
 new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
data: {
      dino: d_var,
      cati: d_catox,
      items: []
    },    
    methods: {
      loadmore: function () {
        axios.get(this.dino)
          .then(response => {
            this.items.push(...response.data);
            this.dino = "/api/search/" + this.items[this.items.length - 1].lid + "/" + this.cati;
          })
      }
    }
})
```

Below is my JSON

```
[
  {
    "Title": "HealthXP1"
  }, 
  {
    "Title": "HealthXP2"
  },
{
    "Title": "HealthXP3"
  },
{
    "lid": "A1234567890"
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: you could use computed property that returns items.slice(0, items.length-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 'v-if' or 'v-show' directive as:

```
<div id="vue-app">
          <div id="myList" v-for="item in items" v-show="item.Title">
                <p>{{item.Title}}</p>
<button v-on:click="loadmore()" class="fluid ui button">Load More</button>
```

that will show that item on the list if the item.Title is defined, otherwise it will not be rendered in DOM

Comment: There are more items than Title. For example description, images, url etc. It is not feasible to use v-show everywhere.

Comment: then you can check if item.lid is defined don't show the item, I added that code as you mentioned every item has a title and this item with lid doesnt have one, so it seemed a correct way to use it as the item that has only lid would'nt be shown as the title there is not defined

Comment: I was able to solve my problem with your solution. I was thinking more from a Python view so I thought that i need to make the changes to my description, images to include v-show. But never thought that by just adding v-show all my other attributes will also reflect the changes by adding v-show just once.